# Calculating the sum of 1/(2n+1) from 1 to m

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the series $$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
I have found out how to do this with $$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2n-1}$$ but I cannot find this. Please help!

Comment: the first one is just the second one, when  $n$ is substituted by $n+1$, plus an extra term

Comment: How do you do the second sum? Any way other than just adding them up?

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to deal with the second, just note that the two are very stricly related, as:
$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2n-1}=1+\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2m+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_1$ be the first sum and $S_2$ be the second sum. Then
$$
S_1 = S_2 - 1+\frac{1}{2m+1}
$$